# PNG image alpha color issue with php

Tags: php, image, alpha

I have this public function:

```
 public function resize($width, $height)
{
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    if($this->_imageType == IMAGETYPE_PNG && $this->_transparent === true){
        imagealphablending($newImage, false);
        imagesavealpha($newImage, true);
        imagefilledrectangle($newImage, 0, 0, $width, $height, imagecolorallocatealpha($newImage, 255, 255, 255, 127));
    }
    imagecopyresampled($newImage, $this->_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
    $this->_image = $newImage;
}
```

My problem appears when I preview the image. It doesn't display alpha color. Can I get some help?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting imagealphablending to true, not false.